# How to use id-name on keydown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js code like this:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
```

Above code works as well (for all textarea(s)). Now I want to devote the above code for all textarea's except this `id: #idname`

---

I tried this:

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'textarea:not(#idname)', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
```

But this code doesn't work, How can I fix it?

Comment: I just checked and with jquery 2.0 this worked perfectly for me this might just be a problem with your id.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zsdapvcz/ Verifies this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(document.activeElement === $("#idname")[0]) return;
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
```

Comment: That condition you have added, never execute for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if (!$(e.target).is("#idname") && e.keyCode===13) {
       //your stuffs
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, instead of devoting all textarea, only permit one, knowing you are using a unique id `#idname` :

**HTML**

```
 <textarea>
     not this one
 </textarea>
 <br />
 <textarea id="idname">
     try this one
 </textarea>
 <textarea>
     not this one
 </textarea>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("#idname").on("keydown", function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            /* do your job here */
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zwxxezy9/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `:not()` to devote the element and `e.which` to capture the key like this:

```
$('textarea:not("#idname")').keydown(function(e){
    if ( e.which == 13 ) alert('Hooray Enter was pressed!!');
});
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gmanou/v6xuLLkz/1/)**